# Connect to your sql server without credentials

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, ssms

I created a project in visual studio and I want to use SQL Server Management Studio to see database. What should be the server name?

On connecting to sql server, it gives error:[image]

I tried finding server name using cmd so the result was:
[image]

**Note:**
My sql server configuration manager doesn't contain any sql server services. I was using sql server 2012 so now I downloaded sql server 2017 but same, so services are shown.

How can I connect to sql server?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to connect to the SQL server if the SQL Server service is not running. Once you have verified your service is running, you can use the  option in the Server name to select your SQL Server Name.

[image]

Comment: Not exactly so.  SQLServer Express allow connection directly to mdf-file. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxds9ett(v=vs.90).aspx. I suspect this is the case

Comment: I'm able to connect to sql server using the credentials by a hosting provider. but I don't want to use that credentials for my other database. How can I get a server name to login using windows authentication?

Comment: @Ingaz thank you for the link but I don't have mdf file. I was first using sql server credentials by a company provider but I no longer have that credentials so I want to have my own sql server credentials or some how I want to login to my sql server.

Comment: Longer explanation is below.

Answer (score 0):

Irfan.

You can connect to SQLServer with two ways:

1. Usually you run SQLServer instance as service and connect using server credentionals
2. Sqlexpress "embedded" style -  connect to mdf/mdb-file. Behind the scenes it will start localdb service and attach db-file.

First way is recommended in most cases.

Run `services.msc` and look for sqlserver instances. If they are down - start one. If they are notexistent - rerun installation and check options.

Comment: Sql server services don't exist. I have installed sql server 2017 but still no services appear in services.msc

Comment: Do I understand correcty that you installed SQLServer 2017 CTP 2.1? Couple of possibly foolish questions: a) Did you install server or only SSMS? b) Just for clarity: you are not running SQLServer in docker?

Comment: I think I installed only SSMS. I installed from the first link of this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms and I don't have any idea of docker.

Comment: SSMS - is just an editor and managment tool. You did not installed SQLServer itself. If you want SQLServer 2017 - https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/evalcenter/evaluate-sql-server-2017-ctp/   . Alternative way - use docker images. If your version of Windows allows them - concider yourself lucky. (Although I've never tried docker on Windows)